# In python, is there a way to output two buttons (or more) onto the screen using classes and inheritance?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pygame

**PROBLEM:**
I'm creating a small game and I'm trying to figure out the main menu screen. I want to have two buttons in certain positions however, I cannot seem to actually get them on the screen.

I've tried calling the Button class I have made (there may be a problem with that, I'm not too sure) and I've tried moving that line of code around. I have also tried creating an instance of the class, however that does not seem to work at all either.

Below is my main game class (parent class):

```
pygame.init()
winWidth = 1000
winHeight= 600
FPS = 27
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (200,0,0)
LIGHTRED = (255,96,96)
TITLE_FONT_SIZE = 60
MENU_FONT = 'oldenglishtext'

class mainMenu():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.title = pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winWidth, winHeight))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.state = 'menu'

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            if self.state == 'menu':
                self.menuEvents()
                self.menuDraw()
                Button(self.screen, 400, 200, 200, 75, RED, LIGHTRED)
            elif self.state == 'options':
                pass

            self.clock.tick(FPS)
    def menuEvents(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

    def menuDraw(self):
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)
        self.drawText('GAME', self.screen, (winWidth//2, winHeight-575),
                      TITLE_FONT_SIZE, BLACK, MENU_FONT)
        pygame.display.update()


    def drawText(self, words, screen, pos, size, colour, fontName):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(fontName, size)
        text = font.render(words, False, colour)
        textSize = text.get_size()
        pos = list(pos)
        pos[0] = pos[0] - textSize[0]//2
        pos[1] = pos[1] - textSize[1]//2
        pos = tuple(pos)
        screen.blit(text, pos)
```

Below is my button class (child class):

```
    def __init__(self, screen, buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, colour, hoverColour):
        super().__init__()
        self.buttonX = buttonX
        self.buttonY = buttonY
        self.buttonWidth = buttonWidth
        self.buttonHeight = buttonHeight
        self.hovered = False
        self.screen = screen

    def mouseHovering(self, pos):
        self.mouse = mouse
        self.button = button
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if button.collidepoint(event.pos):
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.hoverColour, ((self.buttonX,self.buttonY),(self.buttonWidth,self.buttonHeight)))
                return True
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colour, ((self.buttonX,self.buttonY),(self.buttonWidth,self.buttonHeight)))
                return False
    def buttonUpdate(self):
        if self.mouseHovering(pos):
            self.hovered = True
        else:
            self.hovered = False
    def setColour(self, colour, hoverColour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.hoverColour = hoverColour

    def drawButton(self):
        if self.hovered:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.hoverColour,((self.buttonX,self.buttonY),(self.buttonWidth,self.buttonHeight)))
            print("hovered")
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colour, ((self.buttonX,self.buttonY),(self.buttonWidth,self.buttonHeight)))
            print("not hovered")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = mainMenu()
    game.run()
```

I want to have the buttons actually on the screen and be able to change colour when I hover over them. Eventually I will add text and a clicking function but for now I would like to have these basic functions. Currently, the code outputs the game title and nothing else.

Comment: to use two buttons you have to create two instances of class button and you have to draw these buttons in `menuDraw` using `drawButton` for every instance separatelly. And use `mouseHovering` in `menuEvent` to send events to buttons so they can check if you hover button. In current code you do nothing to display buttons.

Comment: pyGame has class `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size of objects like button, player, enemy, etc. And Rect has collidepoint which can be used to check collision with mouse. In `mouseHovering` you use variable `button` which doesn't exists.

Comment: there is no need to use prefix `button` for all variables in class button. it is much shorter to use `self.x` instead of `self.buttonX`. And when you will have other classes like Player, Enemy then they may use also `self.x` instead of `self.playerX`, `self.enemyX` so it is easier to remeber the same variables in all different classes. And if you will keep all object in list or group then you can use `.x` for all of them without checking if you have to use `.buttonX` or `.playerX` or `.enemyX`

Comment: document [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests to use `UpperCaseNames` for classes - ie. `class MainMenu`, `class Button` but `lower_case_names` for functions, methods and other variables - ie. `def draw_button`, `def mouse_hovering`, etc. Even PyGame uses these rules - ie. class `pygame.Rect()` but function `pygame.draw.rect()` or `set_mode()` , not `setMode()`

Comment: Thank you furas for your help! I understand where I went wrong and I'll definitely check out the link attached. :D

Comment: I have also some buttons on GitHub [Python-Examples/PyGame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame). There are examples from other my answers on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you forgot in `Button.__init__`

```
self.colour = colour
self.hoverColour = hoverColour
```

---

To see two buttons you have to create two instances of class `Button` in `__init__`

```
def __init__ (self):
    self.title = pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winWidth, winHeight))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.running = True
    self.state = 'menu'

    self.button1 = Button(self.screen, 400, 200, 200, 75, RED, LIGHTRED)
    self.button2 = Button(self.screen, 400, 400, 200, 75, RED, LIGHTRED)
```

and later draw buttons in `menuDraw()`

```
def menuDraw(self):
    self.screen.fill(WHITE)

    self.button1.drawButton()
    self.button2.drawButton()

    self.drawText('GAME', self.screen, (winWidth//2, winHeight-575),
                  TITLE_FONT_SIZE, BLACK, MENU_FONT)
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

As for hovering you whould have to use `mouseHovering` in `menuEvent` but you have mistakes in `mouseHovering` - you use variables `mouse` `button` , `even` which doesn't exists in this function and you don't use them as argument in `def mouseHovering(...)`

But you need only `event` as argument because it has information about mouse's position, mouses's buttons, etc

```
def mouseHovering(self, event):
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
```

but this need to keep button size and position in `pygame.Rect()`

```
class Button():

    def __init__(self, screen, buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, colour, hoverColour):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttonX = buttonX
        self.buttonY = buttonY
        self.buttonWidth = buttonWidth
        self.buttonHeight = buttonHeight

        self.hovered = False
        self.screen = screen

        self.colour = colour # forgot
        self.hoverColour = hoverColour

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.buttonX, self.buttonY, self.buttonWidth, self.buttonWidth)
```

And then you can use `mouseHovering` in `menuEvent`

```
def menuEvents(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        self.button1.mouseHovering(event)
        self.button2.mouseHovering(event)
```

---

**EDIT:** Code after other changes. It displays text on button. It uses class `pygame.Rect()` to center text on Button (with some problems but for other elements it center correctly). It generate `draw_text()` only once beause it never change.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WIN_WIDTH  = 1000
WIN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 27

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

RED      = (200, 0, 0)
LIGHTRED = (255, 96, 96)

GREEN      = (0, 200, 0)
LIGHTGREEN = (96, 255, 96)

TITLE_FONT_SIZE = 60
MENU_FONT = 'oldenglishtext'

# --- classes --- (UpperCaseNames)

class Button():

    def __init__(self, screen, x, y, width, height, color, hover_color, text):
        super().__init__()

        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

        self.color = color
        self.hover_color = hover_color
        self.text = text

        self.hovered = False

        # create image with text
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(MENU_FONT, TITLE_FONT_SIZE)
        self.text_image = font.render(text, False, WHITE)
        self.text_rect = self.text_image.get_rect()
        # center text on button
        self.text_rect.center = self.rect.center

    def handle_events(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)

    def update(self):
        pass
        # not needed at this moment

    def draw(self):
        if self.hovered:
            color = self.hover_color
        else:
            color = self.color            

        # draw button
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color, self.rect)
        # draw text on button
        self.screen.blit(self.text_image, self.text_rect)


class MainMenu():

    def __init__ (self):
        self.title = pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.state = 'menu'

        self.button1 = Button(self.screen, 400, 200, 200, 75, RED, LIGHTRED, "HELLO")
        self.button2 = Button(self.screen, 400, 400, 200, 75, GREEN, LIGHTGREEN, "WORLD")

        # generate text only once because it doesn't change 
        self.text_image, self.text_rect = self.draw_text('GAME', (self.screen_rect.centerx, self.screen_rect.bottom-575), TITLE_FONT_SIZE, BLACK, MENU_FONT)

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            if self.state == 'menu':
                self.handle_events()
                self.draw()
            elif self.state == 'options':
                pass

            self.clock.tick(FPS)

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

            self.button1.handle_events(event)
            self.button2.handle_events(event)

    def draw(self):

        self.screen.fill(WHITE)

        self.button1.draw()
        self.button2.draw()

        self.screen.blit(self.text_image, self.text_rect)

        pygame.display.update()


    def draw_text(self, words, pos, size, color, font_name):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(font_name, size) # it could be done once at start in __init__
        image = font.render(words, False, color)
        rect = image.get_rect()
        rect.centerx = pos[0]
        rect.top = pos[1]
        return image, rect

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    game = MainMenu()
    game.run()
#    pygame.quit()
```

[image]